# Loading mocks into an AngularJS unit test

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to setup my AngularJS application to test out controllers, routes, templates and so on, but I'm having an issue getting some of the helper methods provided by the **angular-mocks.js** to work (namely **module** and **inject**).

I'm using testacular to load up the test suite with the following files added before the specs:

```
files = [
  MOCHA,
  MOCHA_ADAPTER,
  '../application/lib/angular.min.js',
  './lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  './lib/angular/angular-scenario.js',
  '../application/application.js',
  './lib/chai.js',
  './lib/chai-should.js',
  './lib/chai-expect.js',
  './spec/**/*.js'
];
```

So far so good, but when I run the tests I get this issue:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
```

Not sure where this is loaded. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to check is that all those files are getting loaded in the test browser. It's surprisingly easy to get a path wrong in your config and not realize it. If you're running testacular with `autowatch`, you can navigate to `http://localhost:9876/context.html` with a browser and use developer tools inspect elements/resources/network and see if anything is missing.

If everything is good there and you're still having problems, post some of your test code and I'll take a look.

UPDATE: It appears (strangely) from the comments in the source for [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1629) (line 1635) that `window.module` is only available with Jasmine. It looks like you're using Mocha instead of Jasmine. This is very likely the culprit.

ANSWER:

I can't rightly take credit for this Matsko, since you figured it out yourself... but it turns out that the current AngularJS stable download and angular-seed contain an older version of ngMock that doesn't support Mocha. Manually replacing the mock file with the latest from the github repo solves the problem. Glad I could help ;-)

Comment: Looks like everything is fine. Where exactly are the helper functions defined in? angular-mocks? angular-loader? angular-scenerio?

Comment: Are these unit tests or e2e tests? I just looked at your file list again and I don't think you need `./lib/angular/angular-scenario.js` in there. It might be causing the problem...

Comment: Are you calling it like this in your tests? `  beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));`

Comment: Module appears to be defined here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1646

Comment: OK found out the problem. Turns out that mocha isn't defined in the ngMock file (it only respects jasmine), however in the ngMock.js file that is on the github repo it is defined. So you need to manually download it from the repo and put that into your test suite. If you download angular from the website (the stable version) or clone the seed repository then it contains the old ngMock.js files and it won't work.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that I can close this :) Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: +1 for telling us about context.html which I didn't see in the docs. That is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and I wanted to provide others with a complete summary of the required steps to get this working.  First let's say you have a module named myApp.  Inside that that module there is a service called myModel.  the myModel service has a method named getItems().

1. Currently, the angular-mocks.js (I am using AngularJS 1.0.6) does not support Mocha.  You will need to visit this [link](https://raw.github.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js%20this) and replace the 1.0.6 version with the one in the master branch from the AngularJS GitHub project. An easy way to do this (if you have wget) is `wget https://raw.github.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js` in the correct directory.  If you use a properly configured Sublime or vim it can also easily pull it down for you.
2. Make sure your karma.conf.js file includes the angular-mocks.js file in files array
3. Somewhere in your tests.js file (maybe at the top level describe) include `beforeEach(module('myApp'));` or whatever you named your main module.
4. If you plan to use the service (or whatever you want to include in the test) in more than one place you can call another beforeEach where needed like this:

`beforeEach(inject(function(myModel) {

  mymodel = myModel;

}));`

otherwise you just can inject where it is needed.  Now the mymodel variable (notice this is the variable you assigned in the beforeEach above) will be available to you for testing in your next blocks. For example, you can now write:

`describe('when fetched', function() {

  it('should return 3 items', function() {

    // console.log(mymodel.getItems());

     expect(mymodel.getItems()).to.have.length(3);

  });

});`